# how to add author info onto git log --oneline --graph

Tags: git

```
git log --oneline --graph
```

[image]

How could I add author info to the results?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use [pretty-format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) instead of oneline:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%d%x09%s" --graph
```

That `%an` adds the author.

Comment: yes, and for the committer's name (although it didn't seem to directly be part of the question) if needed, use `%cn`

Comment: @RomainVALERI Agreed. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats lists *all* the format placeholders possible.